# Highcharts Y-Axis skipped labels when dealing with large array

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

My Y-Axis array :

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"]
```

The chart doesn't show all number, it only shows 1, 3, 5, and so on. 2, 4, 6 is getting skipped. How do I force Highcharts to show all labels?

[image]

[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngendk2o/)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to set the [`label.step`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.step) to `:

```
    labels: {
        step: 1
    }
```

This forces highcharts to render a label for every category/tick.

Comment: Didn't add every tick, but I have problem on the x axis, not on y axis.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is to remove ticks if they are too close to one another. You can force all ticks by using a `tickPositioner`, rather than specifying `categories`:

```
    yAxis: {
        title: null,
        tickPositioner: function () {
            return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24];
        }
    },
```

Note the quotes were removed, i.e. the returned array contains numbers (rather than string literals as was the case in the original question). Not sure why it doesn't work with string literals.

See also http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: your edited answer doesn't work, but the answer before the edit works. Can you change it back so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: in the last answer it's important you remove the quotes around the numbers, did you do that as well? I noticed that *with* the quotes it doesn't work, without the quotes it should work equally well.